# What happens when user dismiss a Form using the Back button?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, freeze, delphi-10.1-berlin

I'm having an issue that my app randomly freezes when the user open and close too much Forms or use the app for several minutes, so I'm doubting if the forms are really being freed from memory.

I'm using this for showing the forms:

```
Form55 := TForm55.Create(Self);
Form55.Show;
```

Some forms have a button to close it and others did not:

```
procedure TForm55.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
Form55.Close;
end;
```

And on the OnClose I have pretty much like this:

```
procedure TForm55.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
// Actions
  Application.ProcessMessages;
  Action := TCloseAction.caFree;
end;
```

But, if the user just tap Back button in the phone, it will trigger the Close event? And if so, that's the correct way to free a form?

Comment: I think that is better if you use TForm55.Create(Application); (also according with Pawel glowacki's book). Also be sure to move the forms that you don't need at startup, in the project options, below the "available forms" box.

Comment: Why are you calling `Application.ProcessMessages;` in `FormClose`?

Comment: I don't know, I'm just desperate for making my app stop freezing. I had to dismiss the TNotificationCenter wich was freezing the app when Virtual Keyboard was shown.